# Kafka Connect JSON Schema does not appear to support "$ref" tags

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jsonschema, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka Connect with JSONSchema and am in a situation where I need to convert the JSON schema manually (to "Schema") within a Kafka Connect plugin.  I can successfully retrieve the JSON Schema from the Schema Registry and am successful converting with simple JSON Schemas but I am having difficulties with ones that are complex and have valid "$ref" tags referencing components within a single JSON Schema definition.

I have several questions:

1. The JsonConverter.java does not appear to handle "$ref".  Am I correct, or does it handle it in another way elsewhere?
2. Does the Schema Registry handle the referencing of sub-definitions? If yes, is there code that shows how the dereferencing is handled?
3. Should the JSON Schema be resolved to a string without references (ie. inline the references) before submitting to the Schema Registry and thereby remove the "$ref" issue?

I am looking at the Kafka Source code module JsonConverter.java below:

```
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java#L428
```

An example of the complex schema (taken from the JSON Schema site) is shown below (notice the "$ref": "#/$defs/veggie" tag the references a later sub-definition)

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/arrays.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "description": "A representation of a person, company, organization, or place",
  "title": "complex-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fruits": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "vegetables": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/veggie" }
    }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "veggie": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "veggieName", "veggieLike" ],
      "properties": {
        "veggieName": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name of the vegetable."
        },
        "veggieLike": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "Do I like this vegetable?"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the actual schema returned from the Schema Registry after it the schema was successfully registered:

```
[
  {
    "subject": "complex-schema",
    "version": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "schemaType": "JSON",
    "schema": "{\"$id\":\"https://example.com/arrays.schema.json\",\"$schema\":\"https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema\",\"description\":\"A representation of a person, company, organization, or place\",\"title\":\"complex-schema\",\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"fruits\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"vegetables\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"$ref\":\"#/$defs/veggie\"}}},\"$defs\":{\"veggie\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"required\":[\"veggieName\",\"veggieLike\"],\"properties\":{\"veggieName\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"description\":\"The name of the vegetable.\"},\"veggieLike\":{\"type\":\"boolean\",\"description\":\"Do I like this vegetable?\"}}}}}"
  }
]
```

The actual schema is embedded in the above returned string (the contents of the "schema" field) and contains the $ref references:

```
{\"$id\":\"https://example.com/arrays.schema.json\",\"$schema\":\"https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema\",\"description\":\"A representation of a person, company, organization, or place\",\"title\":\"complex-schema\",\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"fruits\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"vegetables\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"$ref\":\"#/$defs/veggie\"}}},\"$defs\":{\"veggie\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"required\":[\"veggieName\",\"veggieLike\"],\"properties\":{\"veggieName\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"description\":\"The name of the vegetable.\"},\"veggieLike\":{\"type\":\"boolean\",\"description\":\"Do I like this vegetable?\"}}}}}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the response to NOT include the `$ref`, as per the schema you submitted?

Comment: Yes, the "$ref" is expected, but the question is really about how/where to handle and resolve the "$ref" tags.

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to pre-process them at all. They are part of the JSON Schema standard and so should be understood by JSON Schema implementations. `$ref` is not like some sort of template command. The resolution should be done by the implementation which uses the schema when it's validating your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, the `JsonConverter` in the Apache Kafka source code has no notion of JSONSchema, therefore, no, `$ref` doesn't work and it also doesn't integrate with the Registry.

You seem to be looking for the [`io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-schema-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/json/JsonSchemaConverter.java) class + logic

Comment: This raises two questions (I will put each in separate comments): 1.  Does the schema registry handle valid JSON Schema that have valid "$ref" tags?  Right now, I can successfully submit them to the Schema Registry and it retains the "$ref" tags... so, assuming it handles valid JSON Schemas then it does handle "$ref"... but where?

Comment: Regarding references, you can find that PR here, in the Schema Registry project, not Kafka - https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/1280

Comment: 2. I see that I can use a "$ref" tag to initially submit an array of references, but they need to refer to a separate schema that needs to be submitted separately.  While this is useful in some circumstances, it does not handle the situation where "$ref" is embedded in a complex schema...

Comment: 3.  I reviewed the pull request you referenced... I believe this applies to extending AVRO support for referencing by name independent earlier submitted schemas, but does not reference anything about JSON Schema support for inline/embedded "$ref" tags... I guess the question is this: can we confirm "$ref" tags from valid JSON Schemas is supported?

Comment: OK... I think I answered my own question... like you said:  1. embedded "$ref" are not handled, 2. "$ref' can be used when JSON Schemas are previously posted to Schema Registry, 3. Preprocessing probably is needed to remove $ref" tags and de-reference embedded tags

Comment: one last question: you state that JSONConverter does not handle "$ref", and the Schema Registry does not do anything with the JSON Schema, how do consumers/producers handle or validate their message against a JSON Schema should the JSON Schema have embedded "$ref" tags?

Comment: No, no. There are two different classes. [`JsonSchemaConverter` is what you want.](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-schema-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/json/JsonSchemaConverter.java), which is in the Registry source-code not `JSONConverter`  from Kafka sources

Comment: OK.  I looked through JsonSchemaConverter.java and it looks like (by using the org.everit.json code) the $ref gets resolved... So, I guess I can assume (perhaps incorrectly) that the Schema Registry can resolve the $ref tags... but then why do I get unresolved $ref tags in the response from the Schema Registry?  I guess I am misunderstanding your point (my apologies... BTW: thanks for all of your great help!)

Comment: I've not dug into JSON support on the Registry, only Avro, but AFAIK, the references only get resolved during de/serialization, not on the server-side, so if you use an HTTP request, then you just get the schema text as-is